# Generic descendant of TObjectList<T> in Delphi XE violates memory of ancestor

Tags: delphi, generics

I discovered a strange problem in Delphi XE concerning a generic type def. 
I created a derivative of *TObjectList* that include a number of classes (in example fIndex). Then I create a descendant class *TMyButtonlist* that contains a link to an owner. 
The object *fIndex* is not created, so must be **nil** on destruction. But when I set the *fOwer* variable, the *fIndex* variable gets the same pointer, and crashes at destruction.

```
type
  TMyObjectList<T:class> = class(TObjectList<T>)
  private
    fIndex:TStringList;
  public
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

  TMyButtonList = class(TMyObjectList<TButton>)
  private
    Owner:TObject;
  end;

destructor TMyObjectList<T>.Destroy;
begin
  fIndex.Free;
  inherited;
end;

procedure TMainForm.btnClick(Sender: TObject);
var
  Buttonlist:TMyButtonList;
begin
  Buttonlist:=TMyButtonList.Create;
  Buttonlist.Owner := Self;
  ButtonList.Free;
end;
```

Comment: does it happen only in XE? i've test in D2010, no problems found.

Comment: And what is your question? Bug reports should go to [Quality Central](http://qc.embarcadero.com/), not Stack Overflow.

Comment: That bug has been fixed for XE2, see http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=88267

Comment: @teran: Maybe he hasn't applied the latest update.

Comment: Although the before mentioned QC entry is marked as fixed in some build that is before XE Update 1 Ramons code does not run in XE Update 1. In 2010 and XE2 Update 4 it does. Also check http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=98229